# laravel transfer relation from user to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table called `lands` which has the lands that belong to `users`, the user can occupy another user land and take it. So, I want to change the `user_id` in lands table to make it belong to the occupier.

Lands table:

```
$table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->smallInteger('size');
        $table->smallInteger('type')->default(0)->comment('0 is village, 1 is city ');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

is there a method in eloquent to change the `user_id` to match new user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways via Eloquent to do this:

**Making the `user_id` fillable**:

if you make the user_id fillable within the `Land` model, you can fill it via a simple

```
$land->update(['user_id' => $newUser->id])
```

In your code.

**Another choice is the recommended Eloquent way**:

Use

```
$land->user()->dissociate();
$land->user()->associate($newUser->id);
$land->save();
```

To change the user currently stablished under the `BelongsTo` relationship.